# How to use two HDR/EXR Environmental textures in the same scene and split the two top from bottom

Tags: shader-nodes, hdri

[image]

[image]

Please take a look at the node set up, I have tried these two methods and both resulting in distorted color and hdr's not split at all but both still meshed even with messing around fac values. any help would be appreciated.  thank you ☺

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither of those methods make much sense, because you're acting on color rather than coordinates.  The output of each of your nodes is a color; Y in this context is the green channel of each image.

Instead, we're interested in mixing on the basis of *where* the world sample is.  We can do that like this:

[image]

We're looking up colors on two different environmental textures, then mixing on the basis of *where* our lookup is: if the generated texture coordinates Z value is less than 0, we use one image; otherwise, we use the other image.

Comment: thanks! simple enough, I will pay more attention to the logic .